# YouTube Data API: 'A project number must contain exclusively numeric values'

Tags: youtube-data-api

Our organisation has been asked to submit a [data audit form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_audited_developer_requests_form?hl=en). After submitting the form, the error code says: 'A project number must contain exclusively numeric values'.

Anyone else experiencing this problem and any tips on how to solve it?

The project number is definitely correct. 12 numbers in our case.

Comment: Does your "12 numbers" (12 digits?) include leading, trailing, or in-between blank spaces?

Comment: Only numbers and no other characters or blank spaces. I’m wondering if the reason is that our previous audit was completed in April 2020 (15 months ago), and the form says "If you have been audited in the past 12 months".Could that mean that we need to start a new audit process? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/quota_and_compliance_audits